# How to make a time-limited stream from http connection

Tags: java, android, http

How can I modify this method so it keeps the connection going only for a limited amount of time? I want to get output stream after 5 sec connection.

```
 public boolean downloadUrlToStream(String urlString, OutputStream outputStream) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        final URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        // you can use BufferedInputStream and BufferOuInputStream
        IOUtils.copy(stream, outputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
        Log.i(getTag(), "Stream closed all done");
        return true;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            IOUtils.close(urlConnection);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HtppURLConnection has method: `setConnectTimeout(int time)` where time is timout time in milliseconds.
You can set it like: `urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);` which means it has timeout for 5 seconds. And then catch SocketTimeoutException.

```
try {
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
//your stuff hear
} catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
//process exception
} finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: It does not work. Connection timeout works if not http response while 5 sec.

Comment: But what do you want? Keep alive httpconnection only for 5 seconds and doesn't matter whether it is downloading, doing smth. or not?

Comment: @user3518056 , maybe method `se‌​tReadTimeout(mili sec)` will help you. Try it.

Comment: It does not work too. I want to get output stream after 5 sec connection.